# Are there test statistics for which a larger sample size does not tend to produce a smaller p-value?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

I'm assuming that there is a genuine population effect.

By test statistics I mean test statistics that are in accepted use, and not a hypothetical test statistic that a reader might simply make up.

If the notion of a test statistic for which a larger sample size does not tend to produce a smaller p-value is incoherent, why?

Comment: Ones where the null is true? Outside of that, I imagine none that are widely accepted, since inconsistent tests tend to be avoided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said by Glen_b, the short answer is no as this would make the test inconsistent.

However, you can achieve what you want by using a compromise power analyses in which the critical values are changed as a function of $N$. Let me cite the relevant part from [Faul et al. (2007, pp. 176)](http://www.ulouvain.be/cps/ucl/doc/stat/documents/GPower3-BRM-Paper.pdf), the paper which presents [`G*Power 3`](http://www.gpower.hhu.de/), the software for running such analyses:

> In compromise power analyses (Erdfelder, 1984; Erdfelder et al., 1996;
>   Müller, Manz, & Hoyer, 2002), both $\alpha$ and $1 - \beta$ are
>   computed as functions of the effect size, $N$, and the error
>   probability ratio $q = \beta/\alpha$. To illustrate, setting $q$ to 1
>   would mean that the researcher prefers balanced Type I and Type II
>   error risks ($\alpha = \beta$), whereas a $q$ of 4 would imply that
>   $\beta = 4\alpha$ (cf. Cohen, 1988). Compromise power analyses can be
>   useful both before and after data collection. For example, an a priori
>   power analysis might result in a sample size that exceeds the
>   available resources. In such a situation, a researcher could specify
>   the maximum affordable sample size and, using a compromise power
>   analysis, compute $\alpha$ and $1-\beta$ associated with, say, $q = \beta/\alpha=4$. Alternatively, if a study has already been conducted
>   but has not yet been analyzed, a researcher could ask for a reasonable
>   decision criterion that guarantees perfectly balanced error risks
>   (i.e., $\alpha = \beta$) given the size of the sample and the critical
>   effect size in which he or she is interested. Of course, compromise
>   power analyses can easily result in unconventional significance levels
>   greater than $\alpha = .05$ (in the case of small samples or effect
>   sizes) or less than $\alpha = .001$ (in the case of large samples or
>   effect sizes). However, we believe that the benefit of balanced Type I
>   and Type II error risks often offsets the costs of violating
>   significance level conventions (cf. Gigerenzer, Krauss, & Vitouch,
>   2004).

References:
Faul, F., Erdfelder, E., Lang, A.-G., & Buchner, A. (2007). G*Power 3: A flexible statistical power analysis program for the social, behavioral, and biomedical sciences. *Behavior Research Methods*, 39(2), 175–191. http://doi.org/10.3758/BF03193146